# GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP does not exist when cross-compiling

Tags: c++, opengl, cross-compiling, codeblocks, mingw32

I am cross-compiling on Linux, wanted to compile for Windows with MingW32 using Code::Blocks, followed instructions on this page:
[link](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Code%3a%3aBlocks_and_Cross_Compilers), it seems to work, but the problem is only one OpenGL instruction:
`glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);`.
The compiler tells "GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP was not declared in this scope".
 What I am doing wrong?
When I do the same for Linux using the default GNU GCC Compiler everything is fine.

Comment: Do you have the same version of OpenGL on both OS?

Comment: Sorry I have badly formulated my question, now its seems to be ok. I am compiling only on Linux

Comment: What are you using for your [OpenGL loading library](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library)?

Comment: I am using the SDL like this - SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) and then SDL_SetVideoMode( width, height, 16, SDL_OPENGL ); you mean that? Or just the including? I use
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

Comment: @Tom: That's not OpenGL loading, but OpenGL context creation.

Comment: I worked this out by adding glew.h to my mingw include directory, and using glew.h instead of gl.h and glu.h. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows OpenGL ABI only covers OpenGL-1.1 which means, that any OpenGL functionality that goes beyond that version can be reached only through the *extension mechanism*.

In your case all you need is an additional token. There should be an additional set of include directories for your MinGW cross compiler. At least one in `/usr` and one in `/usr/local` (by that I do not mean the usual `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include` directories).

Head over to http://opengl.org/registry grab the `glext.h` header provided there and put it into the directory `/usr/local/$MINGW_INCLUDE/GL`. Then add this file to the headers included in your programs source code. That should give you the token.

Comment: I already have glext.h in my mingw directory, but I worked it out other way - I have used the glew.h header from [here](http://julianibarz.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/glew-1-5-4-mingw32/) and have replaced gl.h and glu.h with glew.h... now it is working. Thank You.